# Cómo grafico una ecuacion igualada a cero con python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

estoy incursionando en la programación con python enfocada al área matemática, más especificamente con la libreria matplotlip y numpy. Estoy tratando de graficar la siguiente ecuación:
x^2 + y^2 + z = 0

El siguiente codigo no me da error, sin embargo comparando con un resultado en GeoGebra3D, noto una diferencia en la orientacion de plano, y tengo la duda de si la omisión del cero de la ecuación provoca algo.

Al final esta la grafica obtenida con python, la obtenida con GeoGebra3D esta orientada en el plano negativo, no en el positivo.

tengo lo sgte;

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

# Make data.
X = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
Y = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
Z = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)

# Ecuacion que necesito
XX = ((X**2)+(Y**2)+Z)

ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, XX, alpha=0.5, cmap=cm.Accent, rstride=2, cstride=2)

plt.show()
```

[image: Grafica obtenida en python, la que obtengo en GeoGebra esta orientada hacia el eje negativo]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema es que no estas despejando la ecuación de forma correcta:

Si tenemos la ecuación `x^2+y^2+z=0`, para generar los puntos de la curva tenemos que despejar una de las incógnitas.

Si despejamos `Z`, nos quedaria → `z = -(x^2+y^2)`. Por lo tanto tu codigo deberia ser:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

# Make data.
X = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.01) # Aqui he aumentado la densidad de puntos para tener una curva mas suave
Y = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.01)
#Z = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25) # No necesitamos puntos de grid para z

Xc, Yc = np.meshgrid(X, Y) # Cambiamos el nombre para no confundirnos
Zc = -(np.add((Xc**2),(Yc**2))) # Estos son realmente los puntos de tu curva!

ax.plot_wireframe(Xc, Yc, Zc, alpha=0.2, cmap=cm.Accent, rstride=5, cstride=5)

plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y por esto efectivamente la curva esta orientada en el plano negativo como comentabas.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, efectivamente ese era el inconveniente, ya lo pude aplicar a esa ecuación y a otra que también estoy graficando (2yx-z = 0).